# VARMAX model in r | Fit VARMA model including exogenous variable

Tags: r, time-series, references, vector-autoregression, moving-average

Working on VARX model and I want to include MA term here but I have not found any package in R to build VARMAX model. MTS package can be used to fit VARMA model but I want to include exogenous variables while fitting the model.

is there any R package available for VARMAX modeling? if not then any alternative for this?

Comment: There is probably no package/function for VARMAX. You could use VARX instead.

Comment: Ok, but then how do I include ma term in the model?

Comment: You do not. The AR part approximates the missing MA part. E.g. among VAR and VARMA, the latter is the more general and also the more parsimonious model. However, it is difficult to estimate, and so we use VAR instead as an approximation.

Comment: but any alternative you can suggest if I want to include MA term. One way is, I can use python package but that is too slow when I integrate that in R notebook so I am looking for R package/any other way?

Comment: No wonder it is slow. That need not be Python's fault. I wrote above that VARMA(X) is hard to estimate, thus slow. Why do you insist on VARMA(X)?

Comment: I am creating a comparison notebook for VARX and VARMAX models. Want to understand the performance comparison of these models.

Comment: Looks like you have got your answer: VARMA(X) is way slower than VAR(X).

Comment: Yup. Understood. One question I still have. In VARMA, while calculating MA, the equation uses residuals lag so how current time t residual gets calculated without having prediction value?

Comment: That is the tricky part that makes VARMA so much harder to estimate than VAR. You have to guess initial values $\hat\varepsilon_1^{(0)},\hat\varepsilon_0^{(0)},\dots,\hat\varepsilon_{1-q}^{(0)}$ of the errors together with the initial values of all the parameters. The you propagate the system through time to obtain errors $\hat\varepsilon_2^{(0)},\hat\varepsilon_3^{(0)},\dots$. Then adjust the initial guesses  from $^{(0)}$ to $^{(1)}$ so as to increase the likelihood. Then iterate until the likelihood stops increasing (up to some level of precision).

Comment: Hi Richard, reaching out to you again regarding the panel var model. I was looking into an example for it in r but no one providing end-to-end examples like fitting models to forecast for new data panel data points. Can you help me out here, please?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/panelvar/versions/0.5.2/topics/pvargmm

This package I am using for panel var

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with that package.

Comment: Okay, Thank you